# Override application pool settings in web config - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config

I want to ask whether we can override settings of application pool like StartMode, Idle Time-out in web config of ASP.NET core web application?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out how to override application pool attr?

Comment: No and i dont think it is possible using web config. I ended up making changes directly in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of research, i ended up making changes directly in IIS.